# LaunchScreen is not showing labels?

Tags: swift

Here is a picture of the launch story board:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdKgE.jpg

here is the picture when I start the simulator up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLJxq.jpg

constraints:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/snc5g.jpg

As you can see the label is hidden but the background color remains. I can change the background color and it reflects the simulator. I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, and rebooting simulator. No luck.

Comment: Please add the constraints applied to the views

Comment: Also your changes might take a while to update.

Comment: @Claudio https://imgur.com/a/yV6rxK5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting constraints, eg: the `title.centerY` and `title.top` constraint. Based on your print, I believe the best approach is to move your labels into a `UIStackView` and add a constraint to `centerY` it on its parent view. Also add a `leading` and `trailing` constraint in relation to the safeArea. Finally on the stackView you can change its spacing value to 3.5 and set the alignment property to center.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do i add a new ImageView to the storyboard?

Comment: @dz1002 if you want your image to be on the background, simply add `UIImageView` and move it below the stackView, constraining it to the sides. If you want to add an image inside the stackView, simply add an image and move it inside the stackView. You can move the imageView on the subViews tree, on the left by dragging them.